# Why does this method not work without static?

Tags: php, methods

The following method orders an array into a hierarchy.

It works fine if you run it once, however if you call the method more than once with different nodes_array it does not clear the static array, and therefore appends it to the first nodes_array.

```
// ORDER NODES
public function order_nodes_function($nodes_array,$parent_id, $level) { 
    static $j=0;
    static $ordered_nodes_array=array();
    for($t=0;$t<count($nodes_array);$t++){
        if($nodes_array[$t]['parent_id']==$parent_id){
            $ordered_nodes_array[$j]=$nodes_array[$t];
            $ordered_nodes_array[$j]['depth']=$level;
            $j++;
            $this->order_nodes_function($nodes_array, $nodes_array[$t]['node_id'], $level+1);
        }
    }
    return $ordered_nodes_array;
}
```

Therefore I have tried to build a method that doesn't use the static variables, but it doesn't work, any ideas what I am doing wrong?...

```
// ORDER NODES
public function order_nodes_function($nodes_array,$parent_id,$level,$ordered_nodes_array,$j) { 
    for($t=0;$t<count($nodes_array);$t++){
        if($nodes_array[$t]['parent_id']==$parent_id){
            $ordered_nodes_array[$j]=$nodes_array[$t];
            $ordered_nodes_array[$j]['depth']=$level;
            $j++;
            $this->order_nodes_function($nodes_array, $nodes_array[$t]['node_id'], $level+1, $ordered_nodes_array, $j);
        }
    }
    return $ordered_nodes_array;
}
```

Comment: Please define (but it doesn't work) ?? you get an error? No Result? Wrong result? Computer crash?

Comment: Just remove static keyword for both j and array from first code sample and give it a try

Comment: Thanks Joraid, in the second example the $ordered_nodes_array doesn't seem to be getting passed for the recursive function, as it is only returning the top level nodes.

Comment: Thanks Akshay, if I remove the static then the recursive function wont work in that it will only return the top level nodes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `static` variable is initialized only once and its' state is kept across the whole run of the program. So when you use

```
static $ordered_nodes_array=array();
```

it is initialized as an empty array only once and from now every time you refer to `$ordered_nodes_array` in this scope you are using the variable with the last set value. That's why it doesn't get reset in subsequent calls.

In the second example you pass the value of the `$ordered_nodes_array` to the recursive function, but manipulating it in another scope doesn't change the array in the original function (as only value is passed, not the reference - effectively this creates two different variables in the memory).

You have different options here:

1. Either catch the return value of your recursive function and add it to the return value. Something like this (I don't know the details of your implementation):

   ```
   $orderd_nodes_array[] = $this->order_nodes_function(
       $nodes_array, 
       $nodes_array[$t]['node_id'], 
       $level+1, 
       $ordered_nodes_array, 
       $j
   );
   ```
2. Pass the reference of your array to the recursive function instead of the value:

   ```
   public function order_nodes_function(
        $nodes_array,
        $parent_id,
        $level,
        &$ordered_nodes_array,
        $j
   ) { ... }
   ```

   Note the `&` sign before `$ordered_nodes_array`. It tells the interpreter that the variable should be passed by reference instead of value. This means that it will stay as one variable in the memory and any modification made inside of this function will have effect on the original array.
3. Create a property in your class and manipulate on the property.

   ```
   class myClass
   {

        protected $orderedNodeList;

        public function __construct()
        {
            $this->orderedNodeList = array();
        }

        public function orderNodes(...)
        {
            $this->orderedNodeList[] = ...;
        }
   }
   ```

This way you will have access to the ordered list anywhere inside of your class. And as long as you use different objects to order the lists the ordered ones will never mix up.

Comment: Thanks Michal for such a concise answer. As you stated it was the & that was needed. Thanks again, J

Answer (score 0):

I would assume that $j is not being passed into this function.

also order_nodes_function seems to be completely different in the two examples

Comment: Thanks Matthew, they are the same function however the first one has static variables, the second one I pass the static variables back to the function so that it doesn't require the variabels to be set as static.

Comment: Have you tried echo'ing out the value of $j? and try $j++ echo $j before it gets to the for loop?